# How to customize strong parameter in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i'm a rails newbie and I got a problem.
When I user a strong parameter:

```
params.require(:project).permit(:project_name, :real_time)
```

I want to use it do update the project:

```
@project.update_attributes(user_project_params)
```

but before that, i want to change the value of

```
:real_time
ex: :realtime += 2
```

please tell me how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

Before calling **user_project_params** update the **params**

```
  params[:project][:real_time] += 2
```

Otherwise use [callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)

Answer (score 1):

Any predefined modifications to the model objects are always done in model.

You can write a method in model and call it using callbacks

```
class Project< ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :update_real_time

  private
    def update_real_time
      self.real_time= self.real_time +2
    end
end
```